# Какие инструменты вы используете для визуального отображения архитектуры front-end приложений?

Tags: архитектура, веб-программирование, frontend

Разрабатывая front-end часть крупного веб приложения с большим количеством модулей, сервисов и контроллеров, сталкиваюсь с необходимостью схематично отображать его архитектуру. Первая мысль, которая приходит в голову - взять лист бумаги и карандаш, и нарисовать эту схему от руки. Вторая - сделать то же самое в фотошопе. Но, возможно, для этой цели есть какой-то специализированный софт? Естественно, я не ожидаю, что он рассчитан обязательно на фронтенд, а наверняка он более универсален.

Comment: Карандаш и бумага

Answer (score 1):

Можно юзать программы для mind-map карт http://blog.akuleplevat.me/top-10-programm-dlya-postroeniya-mind-map/

Или проектировать интерфейсы в axure pr.

Answer (score 1):

Удобно использовать карты памяти. Для лучшего запоминания подбираю картинки подходящие по смыслу.

Пример карты ума без картинок, просто блоки и информация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удобный софт:

- [mindmanager - платный](https://www.mindjet.com/mindmanager/)
- [xmind - бесплатный](http://www.xmind.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Скачивал себе старую версию MS Visio (portable) и без проблем рисовал схемки.